# Keep a parameterized path on maven tools.jar dependency

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

We have a custom taglet for our javadocs that requires `tools.jar` as a dependency, but maven hardcodes the jar location in the released pom.xml.

For that dependency in maven we use the [${java.home} parameter in our pom.xml](https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/blob/develop/pom.xml#L310), but after the project is built the path for that tools.jar is hardcoded to whatever JDK it was built with:

```
cat ~/.m2/repository/.../client.pom
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

I've thought about changing the scope to `test` but then we can't use the `${java.home}` parameter.

Is there a way to either keep the parameterized path, reconfigure the pom/project so the javadocs are separate, or make maven realize it won't *need* it at runtime?

Comment: you shouldn't care about this path. since it's system dependency, it's not transitive, the projects that depend on your project don't inherit it.

Answer (score 0):

Maven supports custom taglets directly using the `maven-javadoc-plugin`.

For more information, please see [the official Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/taglet-configuration.html). It is so clearly described that it doesn't make sense repeating the code here. This can be setup in the `<report>` section or the `<build>` section. Within the `<build>` section, you would likely need to custom tie it to the appropriate build phase too.